# wordpress wp_nav_menu before after

Tags: wordpress

```
              <nav>
                <ul class="menu sf-js-enabled">
                    <li class="item1">
                        <span><a href="#" title="">menuitem-1</a></span>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">submenu-1-1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">submenu-1-2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item2">
                        <span><a href="#" title="">menuitem-2</a></span>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">submenu-2-1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">submenu-2-2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">submenu-2-3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">submenu-2-4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

I am trying to make a custom wordpress menu, but i have a problem with this code. As you can see there is a span tag before menuitem-1 and menuitem-2 and a close span tag too, but there isn't around submenu items.

I tried to do with this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('container' => 'nav', 'container_class' => ' ', 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'menu sf-js-enabled', 'before' => '<span>', 'after' => '</span>') );?>
```

but if i use this method there are also span tags around submenu items but i dont need those tags.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom class "my_nav_walker" insert to my function.php and modified these lines of the original class from class-walker-nav-menu.php

now works fine!

```
$item_output = ($depth == 0 ? $args->before . '<span>' : $args->before); //MODIFIED LINE original --> $item_output = $args->before;
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
$item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
$item_output .= '</a>';
$item_output .= ($depth == 0 ? $args->after . '</span>' : $args->after); //MODIFIED LINE original --> //$item_output .= $args->after;
```

then put this to my header

```
<?php 
$walker = new my_nav_walker;
wp_nav_menu(array(
'container' => 'nav',
'container_class' => ' ',
'theme_location' => 'primary',
'menu_class' => 'menu sf-js-enabled',
'walker' => $walker));
?>
```